# How can I add rel="nofollow to my ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Users")
```

I would like to make the link include the following:

```
title="Register your ID" 
rel="nofollow"
```

Is there a way that I can do this with MVC3?

Comment: If you don't want to use an action link you can alternatively do: <a href="@Url.Action("Register", "Users")" title="Register your ID" rel="nofollow">Register</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the proper overload of the [`ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) method:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Register",                           // linkText
    "Register",                           // actionName
    "Users",                              // controllerName
    null,                                 // routeValues
    new {                                 // htmlAttributes
        title = "Register your ID", 
        rel = "nofollow" 
    }
)
```

Should generate (assuming default routes setup):

```
<a href="/Users/Register" rel="nofollow" title="Register your ID">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Users", null,
    new {title = "Register your ID", rel="nofollow")
```

The framework will parse that object and place the items as attributes in the rendered anchor.