# Is it possible to redirect from action controller in MVC to another website using the nofollow attribute?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I'm implementing a counter for links from my website to external websites. From the view I call a controller action and from here I redirect to the external website after collecting some statistics.

In the action controller i have this code

```
return Redirect(url);
```

Is it possible to redirect from here but passing the equivalent of rel=nofollow of "a" element?
Or the only option is to have the normal link in the view and when the user clicks, I call the api through Javascript updating the statistics in async way?

Thks in advance

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793288/how-can-i-add-rel-nofollow-to-my-actionlink

Comment: I was trying to find a way to do a redirect directly from controller (with nofollow) but I think is not possible. Thks anyway